# Combining two mismatched Anki decks

Tags: anki

I have been working my way for several months through an Anki deck for a foreign language. The deck is for level A1 of the foreign language and, because I have been using it for some months, it contains critical information about my progress. The fields are

> Foreign_language_word, English_Translation, English_note

Recently I acquired a very nice deck for the A2 level. The A2 deck has somewhat different information in each note than the A1 deck. Specifically, it contains the following fields:

> Foreign_language_word, English_Translation, Foreign_language_note, Foreign_language_audio

I have exported the A2 deck as a text file that includes information about the relevant audio-file for each note. What I would like to do now is change the A1 deck so that each note comprises the following, combined set of fields.

> Foreign_language_word, English_Translation, English_note, Foreign_language_note, Foreign_language_audio

If it is possible to do that, then I will be able to

1. expand the A2 text file so that it includes a blank English_note
   field, and
2. import the A2 text file into the existing A1 deck,

thereby retaining all my existing "due" information and integrating the new word list together with the old. Finally, I'll add appropriate audio to my existing notes.

The problem I'm facing is that early step! How do I add extra fields to my existing A1 notes while retaining the important information about my prior learning?